# Obtaining files from group with pathsForResourcesOfType

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a group called initialdata in my main bundle containing 7 JPG's.  From what I've read the code below should give me an array with all the JPG's located in that group but the array is always 0.  What could be the problem?

```
NSArray *namesArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"initialdata"];
NSLog(@"namesarraycount=%i",namesArray.count);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you created folders instead of creating just group? You have to make sure that you created physical folders and subfolders. The above command should work after that.

Comment: Do you mean a folder in finder? Yes I have a folder. Still I get 0 objects.